# how to Pivot just one column based on a common value

Tags: sql, oracle, pivot

i have a result set something similar to this

[image]

and i would like the result to be as

[image]

Any suggestions please

Answer (score 1, accepted):

very similar to question asked before, you could use listagg and comma separated output.

select c1, 
       listagg(c2, ',') within group (order by c2) as col2
from t1
group by c1;

posted test script in liveSql. https://livesql.oracle.com/apex/livesql/s/gj16yorj8qd0r7mi7whowv89a

Answer (score 1):

If you know there are three values, you can use `row_number()`:

```
select t.col1,
       max(case when seqnum = 1 then col2 end) as col_a,
       max(case when seqnum = 2 then col2 end) as col_b,
       max(case when seqnum = 3 then col2 end) as col_c
from (select t.*, row_number() over (partition by col1 order by col2) as seqnum
      from t
     ) t
group by t.col1;
```

Comment: The challenger is that i cannot be sure that there will only be 3 values.

Comment: Thank you for your response, Gordon. I am guessing coalesce is the best option but selecting them as coma separated values